# MySQL 8.0 Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort

Tags: mysql

MySQL 8.0 server is randomly crashing.

Server Info:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
CPU(s):                14
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-13
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             14
RAM:                   16G
```

I'm getting the following error.

```
mysqld got signal 11 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x7f692c2aed70
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7f69a82f0bf0 thread_stack 0x100000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x3d) [0x200098d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(print_fatal_signal(int)+0x2df) [0xf16ebf]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0xa5) [0xf16f75]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf630) [0x7f69c25f4630]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(page_cur_search_with_match_bytes(buf_block_t const*, dict_index_t const*, dtuple_t const*, page_cur_mode_t, unsigned long*, unsigned long*, unsigned long*, unsigned long*, page_cur_t*)+0x1d0) [0x21dd1c0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(btr_cur_search_to_nth_level(dict_index_t*, unsigned long, dtuple_t const*, page_cur_mode_t, unsigned long, btr_cur_t*, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long, mtr_t*)+0x1f54) [0x22f67b4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Row_sel_get_clust_rec_for_mysql::operator()(row_prebuilt_t*, dict_index_t*, unsigned char const*, que_thr_t*, unsigned char const**, unsigned long**, mem_block_info_t**, dtuple_t const**, mtr_t*, lob::undo_vers_t*)+0x10f) [0x223cfaf]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(row_search_mvcc(unsigned char*, page_cur_mode_t, row_prebuilt_t*, unsigned long, unsigned long)+0x204e) [0x2241aae]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(ha_innobase::index_read(unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int, ha_rkey_function)+0x3d6) [0x20fd036]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handler::ha_index_read_map(unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, ha_rkey_function)+0x3c1) [0x102c621]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(RefIterator<false>::Read()+0x134) [0x12e8b94]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Query_expression::ExecuteIteratorQuery(THD*)+0x29e) [0xe824fe]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Query_expression::execute(THD*)+0x2f) [0xe8285f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_dml::execute(THD*)+0x189) [0xe05319]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(mysql_execute_command(THD*, bool)+0x9f0) [0xdac9c0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dispatch_sql_command(THD*, Parser_state*)+0x41a) [0xdb06aa]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dispatch_command(THD*, COM_DATA const*, enum_server_command)+0xd3e) [0xdb194e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(do_command(THD*)+0x207) [0xdb3b47]
/usr/sbin/mysqld() [0xf07620]
/usr/sbin/mysqld() [0x2511165]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7ea5) [0x7f69c25ecea5]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7f69c0c06b0d]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (7f692c50a210): SELECT * FROM xxxx WHERE product_code = 'PSRC20' <-- Different query and different database every time
Connection ID (thread ID): 26
Status: NOT_KILLED
```

I'm guessing it's happening due to MySQL binlog. For binlog, I'm using the following config

```
server-id= 1
log_bin=bin.log
log-bin-index=bin-log.index
max_binlog_size=1500M
binlog_format=row
log_bin_trust_function_creators=1
binlog_expire_logs_seconds=300
```

Is my assumption that binlog could cause this issue? If yes, how can I tweak it?
If no, what could be the possible reason?

FYI, the binlog was configured long time ago. The crash is happening since last month.

Comment: What's the basis for your assumption about binlog being the reason? From the stack trace one can see that the engine abends in the function called `page_cur_search_with_match_bytes`. Also, `SELECT`s don't cause anything to be written to the log, so.

Comment: Is the OS running in 32-bit mode?

Comment: @mustaccio what i think is that binlog lifetime expires in every 5min. When it expires mysql deletes(what i believe) the binlog and creates a new one. during this operation if mysql tries to write in binlog, server crashes. I'm not an expert so i'm not confident with my assumption.

Comment: @RickJames it's running in 64-bit